# Substituir palavras em um texto que são formadas, obrigatoriamente, formadas de letras e números

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu estou tentando substituir palavras em um texto que são formadas, obrigatoriamente, formadas de letras e números.

**Eu tentei isso:**

```
def passwords():

    df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]', '<password>')

    return df
```

**Meus dados:**

```
       A       B                                                  C
   Joana      MG                              minha senha é aaabb123
  Marcos      AM        eu tentei colocar a minha senha varias vezes
   Paulo      RS       eu tenho duas senhas: 321cccppp e r1t2r3t4r5t
```

Meu resultado é horrível:

```
       A       B                                                            C
   Joana      MG                     <password><password><password><password>
  Marcos      AM <password><password><password><password><password><password>
   Paulo      RS <password><password><password><password><password><password>
```

**Bom output:**

```
       A       B                                                  C
   Joana      MG                            minha senha é <password>
  Marcos      AM        eu tentei colocar a minha senha varias vezes
   Paulo      RS       eu tenho duas senhas: <password> e <password>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa regex aqui funciona bem:

```
([0-9]()|[A-Za-z]())+\2\3
```

Basicamente o que essa regex faz é criar 2 grupos de captura, um de números(`[0-9]`) e um de letras maiusculas e minusculas(`[a-zA-Z]`), e então ela verifica se existem os 2 grupos na string(`\2` = grupo 2) e (`\3` = grupo 3).

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AttractiveTatteredIntranet).